# Why signing in doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I'm trying to sign in with an actual user information who's already in database, an error's being rendered "Invalid email/password confirmation.", however it's not supposed.

Why is that?

**controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])

    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password confirmation."
      render :new
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end 

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to signin_path
  end
end
```

**app/views/sessions/new.html**

```
<h1>Sign in</h1>

    <% if flash[:error] %>
       <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
    <% end %>

    <%= simple_form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.input :email %>

      <%= f.input :password%>

      <%= f.button :submit %>

    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
```

**app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    session[:user_id] = nil
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in to access this page."
  end

end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tasks

  attr_accessor :password, :salt, :encrypted_password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :first_name, presence: true,
            length: {maximum: 20}
  validates :last_name,  presence: true,
            length: {maximum: 40}
  validates :email, presence: true,
            format: {with: EMAIL_REGEX},
            uniqueness:  {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, presence: true,
            confirmation: true,
            length: {within: 6..40}

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)

    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
  end

  private
    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")

      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(pass)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{self.salt}--#{pass}")
    end

  end
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Check your assumptions, look in the logs, get `params`, step through your code.

Comment: Did my answer worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, what I see is there is a `confirmation :true` for `password` but you don't have `password_confirmation` field in your `form`. Try including it

`<%= f.input :password_confirmation %>`

and also include it as `attr_accessor` in `User` model.

If you don't want a confirmation field for password, then remove `confirmation: true` for password in validations.

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: {within: 6..40}
```

Comment: I don't need password confirmation field when I log in. It's used for registration.

Comment: @Mike Then just remove `confirmation :true` from validations for password

Answer (score 0):

Try removing :salt and :encrypted_password from the following line in models/user.rb

```
attr_accessor :password, :salt, :encrypted_password
```

change to:

```
attr_accessor :password
```

Those values are stored in the database so chances are you're overwriting the methods created my active-record for those two fields and they're never being initialised.

Comment: Sadly nothing changed.